# Update Sublime Text 2 in Mint 10 Linux

Tags: linux, upgrade

Sublime Text 2 won't let me use it unless I upgrade. Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm new to Linux and all they have is the `tar.bz2` file.  But I know you can update programs with `apt-get` sometimes.  Does anyone know the easiest way to upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) for Sublime Text 2.

This means that, once you enable this repository, you can upgrade Sublime Text 2 using the standard Mint package manager, `apt-get`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-2
```

There are full instructions on [this blog post](http://blog.hugeaim.com/2012/03/13/install-sublime-text-2-in-linux-mint/).

See this question on Ask Ubuntu about [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) so you understand the concept before enabling it.